# Log4j Console Appender Limitations

Tags: java, asynchronous, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am curious about the numbers around the limitations for the Log4j console appender. I have a service that processes messages using a thread pool and logs each event after processing. Before the thread pool approach, the service would just use the main thread for processing all of the messages. This took too long so I implemented a thread pool so each thread can process a subset of the messages as they are independent of each other.

However I started running into an issue where apparently the async queue is full and the threads would discard logs until the queue capacity would be available. I tracked down where this log iscoming from and it’s here due to the discarding policy: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/async/DiscardingAsyncQueueFullPolicy.html#line.49

This is a problem as I need the logs and I need to use a console appender. I added a config to instead use the default policy so we don’t discard logs: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/async/DefaultAsyncQueueFullPolicy.html#line.29

But now the issue is that processing the messages is taking too long, and it makes sense because now when the queue is full, the thread takes time to send logs to the console instead of returning and processing another batch of messages.

My questions:

1. Is there anything I can do to address this issue if I need to use a console appender? Would more cpu/memory help in this case for the threads?
2. Why exactly does the queue get so full quickly? Because when using the main thread to process ALL of the messages (so not batches) we don’t run into this issue but using the threads to batch process the messages we do? Also can we check the log4j queue size programmatically?
3. Can we configure the size of the log4j queue if we’re using a console appender?
4. Is there a logs/second figure for the max to expect using a console appender? so we can compare and see if we’re logging much more somehow.

We want to log the events to console, so we haven’t tried to use a different logger such as to a file. Would that be our only solution here if we are trying to log too many logs/second?

Comment: What do you mean under "console"? Is it a terminal/IDE window or just stdout/stderr redirected to file?

Comment: stdout, don’t believe it’s redirected to a file

Comment: You can write a very very very simple application, and config it use console appender, run application, and exit application. Find where is your log ? Console Appender do not save log to any file.

Comment: Are you using an [`AsyncAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#AsyncAppender) or an [`AsyncLogger`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html)? The latter uses LMAX Disruptor and is much faster.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I have this config set: “Log4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector” which I believe would run all configured appenders in async. I can try using an async logger/appender but would that change anything if I’m logging to std out and not a file? In terms of filling up the logging queue?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your logging queue is filling up is that you increased the performance of your application too much :-). Now you have a bottleneck in the logging appender.

There are some benchmarks comparing a `FileAppender` to a `ConsoleAppender` in [Log4j2 documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/cloud.html). Your figures might vary, but due to the synchronization mechanisms in `System.out`, the console appender is around 20 times slower than the file appender. The bottleneck is not really the filesystem, since redirecting `stdout` to `/dev/null` gives similar results.

To improve performance, you can set the `direct` property on the console appender to `true` (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#ConsoleAppender)). This basically replaces `System.out` with `new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out)` and provides performance on par with the file appender.

You can fine tune the LMAX disruptor using Log4j2 properties (cf. documentation). E.g. `log4j2.asyncLoggerRingBufferSize` allows you to increase the size of the async queue (ring buffer in LMAX terminology).